# alphabetic password not working

Tags: android, passwords, numbers

i am facing a problem in android development in which password with number like (6823969093) is working fine but password with alphabets like (helloworld or hello34world ) is not working.

Thanks

```
final EditText editTextemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    final EditText editTextpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    Button buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    final CheckBox showPasswordCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    showPasswordCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (showPasswordCheckBox.isChecked()){
                editTextpassword.setTransformationMethod(null);
            }else{
                editTextpassword.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
            }
        }
    });
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = editTextemail.getText().toString();
            password = editTextpassword.getText().toString();
            handler = new DBHandler(getBaseContext());
            handler.open();
            handler.addLogIn(email, password);
            handler.close();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

---

Comment: Post your database code, instead. The table creation and the insertion code. I guess it's a very easy to solve issue.

Comment: public static final String TABLE_CREATE3 = "create table logInTable (logInEmail text not null, password text not null);";
this is a query, for table creation.

Comment: and data inserting method is:
public long addLogIn(String logInEmail,String password){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUM_Email,logInEmail);
        values.put(COLUM_Password,password);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME3,null,values);
    }

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means to you.

Comment: not working mean "unable to login with alphabetic password e.g hello65world etc."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Step 1] Go to Edit-text Property of password field.

step 2] Select your password pattern or filter from input-type.

Comment: i have checked the Edit-text properties, but i could not find properties like "pattern" or "filter".

Comment: Namik kalavadia i only mange to find textFilter. which is also not working.

Comment: Khawar ali.. I have edited my answer.. can u find this property of edit text. ?